# ATL linker error: Cannot open input file ***.obj

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

I am trying to use the ATL library in my program. I am using Qt 5.2.

After adding the header files path to the Qt .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/inc/at171/"
```

the first error was:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'atls.lib'
```

This was solved by adding path to the atls.lib:

```
LIBS += "C:/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/lib/ATL/i386/"
```

Now I get the error:

```
LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/lib/ATL/i386/.obj'
```

There are no object files in this folder, but why does it look for one when it requested the atls.lib?

I need some help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how your Makefile is setup, but `LIBS` is generally reserved to be a list of .a, .so, or .lib files. You would want to set `LIBPATH` to specify what directory to search for all the libraries in `LIBS`

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/inc/at171/"
LIB += "atls.lib" # shouldn't be needed: it's already looking for atls.lib.
LIBPATH += "C:/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/lib/ATL/i386/"
```

Comment: As far as I can see there is no LIBPATH macro to use in Qt 5.2 .pro file. (it does not get highlighted as LIBS and INCLUDEPATH does). I did as you suggested anyway and got a different linker error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER':value '1700' doesn't match value 1800 in 'main.obj'.

Comment: That is not good. It's telling you that the compiler used to build main.cpp (main.cc, main.c++, main.c, …) is a different version than the linker. Do you have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed?

Comment: Only Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You made me think (yay!). The Qt 5.2 I have is running msvc2012 compiler and I only had VS2013 installed. I installed VS2012 and compiled using this compiler instead of the VS2013 one that I had selected in Qt.